# Executing inline javascript in Ember.js on page forward/back?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So say I have two routes: `#/one` and `#/two`.  If I place inline `js` to do `alert('foo');` on `#/one` and go to `#/one` to execute the inline `js`, then enter in the address bar `#/two` to navigate myself to the second page, and then press the back button to go back to `#/one`, the inline `js` on `#/one` does not execute a second time.

How do I make sure all `js` not tied to `ember.js` gets executed on page back/forward?

Comment: you are using <script> tags in your handlebars file?

Comment: Can't you place your js code in activate hook on the route?